# Using .htaccess to RewriteRule but every file points to one file

Tags: html, .htaccess

I am currently trying to using .htaccess to do the following:

When `b/` is found in the url, it redirects to `browse.html`. My .htaccess file looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^b/(.*)$    browse.html    [NC,L]
```

I am using Apache version 2.2.31 and here is what my directory looks like:

```
Root
    Root/browse.html
    Root/[css]
              Root/css/browse.css
    Root/[js]
              Root/js/browse.js
```

When I do this, it brings me to browse.html but nothing loads correctly. Every file in the `css` and `js` directories become browse.html. Is there something extra I need to add to this?

Here is what the dev tools directory looks like with the .htacess

```
localhost
         b/?page=1 (browse.html file. Name comes from query string)
         b/[css]
                 b/css/browse.css (blank file)
         b/[js]
                 b/js/browse.js (browse.html instead of browse.js)
```

I have tried putting `RewriteBase /` in between but that does nothing to the problem.

Comment: Where is your .htaccess file? Why do you have the css/js files **inside** the `b/`?

Comment: my .htaccess file is in root directory with the others and im not sure, thats what the .htacess did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rewrite rule is fine. Problem is happening due to your use of relatives paths for css/js/images. While resolving relative paths browser appends it to current page's path.

You can add this rule **above your existing rule:**:

```
RewriteEngine On

# fix css/js paths
RewriteRule ^b/.*((?:js|css)/.+)$ /$1 [NC,R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^b/(.*)$ browse.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: Would I add this to all my pages or just the browse.html page?

Comment: So this worked but it takes away the b/path/ away. It goes from `localhost/b/path/?page=1` to `localhost/?page=1`. How do I get that to stay?

Comment: I added that as my .htacess file and now It is loading my page three times. Any thoughts as to why?

Comment: Only files in `/js/` or `/css/` folders will be redirected to correct path using first rule. There is no other redirect in rules. Test in Chrome dev tool with caching disabled and check in Networking tab what are 301/302 redirect URLs you're getting.

Comment: I am getting a 304 status from an html file that is being called in the browse.html. Everything else is a 200 status.

Comment: There is no `304` in my suggested rules above. There is only a 301 for js and css files. You have some other code/config that is causing this.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to ignore requests if files/folders exists:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^b/(.*)$    browse.html    [NC,L]
```

Comment: When I do this, It gives me the same result. When looking at dev tools, it says `b/ -> [css] [js]`. but the `css` files are all blank and the `js` files are all what browse.html is supposed to be.

Comment: do you have a `b` directory there?

Comment: No. Would I need to create a `b` directory and put all the files in there?

Comment: No, i just wanted to make sure

Comment: which version of apache you use? can you add the exact structure of your folders/files to the question?